# How to catch the last line error message by boost::python

Tags: python, c++, boost

Any way to catch the last line error message from python(using msvc2008)?

```
try
{
    boost::python::exec_file(
        "someScript.py",            
        main_namespace, 
        local_namespace
    );
    return true;
}catch(const boost::python::error_already_set &){
    using namespace boost::python;

    PyObject *exc,*val,*tb;    
    PyErr_Fetch(&exc,&val,&tb);
    boost::python::handle<> hexc(exc), hval(boost::python::allow_null(val)), htb(boost::python::allow_null(tb));
    boost::python::object traceback(boost::python::import("traceback"));

    boost::python::object format_exception(traceback.attr("format_exception"));
    boost::python::object formatted_list = format_exception(hexc, hval, htb);
    boost::python::object formatted = boost::python::str("\n").join(formatted_list);

    std::string const Result = extract<std::string>(formatted);
    std::cout<<Result<<std::endl; //pop out a lot of error messages
}
```

When I output the Result, there contains too many messages, most of the messages are meaningless for the end users.By now I use boost::split to catch the last line of the error messages.

```
//I miss auto so much
typedef boost::container::vector<std::string>::iterator Iter;
std::string const Result = extract<std::string>(formatted);

boost::container::vector<std::string> splitted;
boost::split(splitted, Result, boost::is_any_of("\n"), boost::token_compress_on);

Iter it = std::remove(splitted.begin(), splitted.end(), "");
splitted.erase(it, splitted.end());

return splitted.back();
```